# Click element will select option

Tags: javascript

When you click a certain element, an option will be selected.

For example: you click on a Div element with id="object3", this action will automatically select the Option element "Item 3".

Anyone know a Javascript that can do this?

[HTML example](http://jsfiddle.net/zFuCc/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Click tag will select option</title>
</head>

<body>


<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <ul style="list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <select id="select_items" name="SelectItems">
          <option value="Item1">Item 1</option>
          <option value="Item2">item 2</option>
          <option value="Item3">Item 3</option>
          <option value="Item4">item 4</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </fieldset>

</form>

<div id="object1" style="background-color:#F00;width:30px;height:30px;margin:4px;cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div id="object2" style="background-color:#0F0;width:30px;height:30px;margin:4px;cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div id="object3" style="background-color:#00F;width:30px;height:30px;margin:4px;cursor:pointer;"></div>
<div id="object4" style="background-color:#FF0;width:30px;height:30px;margin:4px;cursor:pointer;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The title is seriously ambiguous. Moreover, a *tag* cannot be clicked, but an *element* can. A tag is 'a' or 'div' while an element is a complete `<div id="a">b</div>`.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me, I have corrected the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define onclick event handler for each div ( in HTML `onclick="doSelect( this )"` or by dynamic binds )

```
function doSelect( el ) {
    var sel_id = el.id.replace( 'object', '' );
    document.getElementById( 'select_items' ).value = 'Item' + sel_id;
}
```

Version with id's

```
var relations = { 'object1': 'item-fire', 'object2': 'item-earth', 'object3': 'item-water', 'object4': 'item-wind' };

function doSelect( el ) {
    document.getElementById( relations[ el.id ] ).selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ntvf. What if you use an id in the options instead of a value, and you don't use numbers in that id? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EqMh4/

Comment: Sounds weird, using options without values. If you need such way, you can use relation array `var relations = { 'object1': 'item-fire', 'object2': 'item-earth', 'object3': 'item-water', 'object4': 'item-wind' };` format `onclick_element_name: option_id_to_select`. Than after use this code as a function body  `document.getElementById( relations[ el.id ] ).selected = true;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do use options with values, but I thought it would be easier if I left them out of the example, because they cannot be used for the code. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help :)